# How to improve: print a tree clockwise?

Tags: java, tree, children, graph-traversal

So I got this question in a google phone interview, they want me to write a method that prints a tree's outer elements clock-wise. Example:

```
                      1
                    / | \
                   4  5  7
                  /  /   /\
                 9   12 3 24
                  \
                  14

                    ^    |
                    |    v
                    |-<--|

            prints 1, 7, 24, 3, 12, 14, 9, 4   
            notice that 5 isnt printed because its not "out"
```

so I came up with this:

```
 TreeNode {
    int val;
    List<TreeNode> children;
 }


 void printTreeClockWise(TreeNode root) {

      if (root == null) return;
      System.out.println(root.val);
      printRight(root);   // recursively prints the outer right nodes
      printLeafs(root);   // recursively prints roots with .children.size() > 0
      printLeft(root);   //recursively prints the left outer nodes
 }
```

I then implemented those helper functions and he said its good. My methods basically recurs to the most left/right/bottom node(to each of the walls) then print. He said my methods are fine and they work, but what if now the tree is huge(cannot fit in memory) and they come from servers as we go, so I cant "reliably" wait till the whole tree is loaded and then print it. How would I update my code? I said I can add a boolean and wait till it's true to then try to decide if that node is print-worthy, like so

```
 TreeNode {
    int val;
    List<TreeNode> Children;
    boolean noMoreChildrenUnder;
 }
```

Then he said the hint is to add a pointer to the parent.

```
    TreeNode parent;
```

Then I had no idea what a parent pointer can help me. Any ideas for using the parent pointer to achieve this printing while not needing to read in the whole tree? Or any optimization I can use here? Thanks!

Comment: More information is needed, like how do you define right nodes vs left node ?  Please post [mcve].

Comment: The childrens are defined as an arrayList. If there is one, left is node.children.get(0) while right is node.children.get(node.children.size()  -1)

Comment: @c0der I think the right nodes are (in the diagram of the tree) those on the rightmost side, and the left nodes those on the leftmost side.

Comment: @Twometer my question is how are they defined ? how can you grammatically tell right from left ?

Comment: @c0der Ah okay I see, sorry. I was wondering the same but somehow misread your comment..

Comment: Add the needed information to the question please, and post mcve.